# Can I use autocompletion for kubectl in zsh?

Tags: autocomplete, kubernetes, zsh, kubectl

I daily find myself doing...

```
$ kubectl --context=foo get pods
  < copy text manually >
$ kubectl --context=foo logs dep1-12345678-10101
```

I would like to cycle through matching resources with

```
$ kubectl --context=foo logs dep1<TAB>
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything with my stock setup. Any ideas?

osx 10.12.3
kubectl v1.4.5
zsh zsh 5.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.0)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Both `bash` and `zsh` supports scripts that completes printed command when you press `<TAB>`. The feature is called *Programmable completion*, and you can find more details about that here: [zsh completion](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/workshops/zsh/completion/completion.html).

Fortunately, you don't need to write your own script - kubectl provides it for zsh > 5.2. Try running this command: `source <(kubectl completion zsh)`.

Another option is to use this tool: https://github.com/mkokho/kubemrr
(disclaimer: I'm the author). The reason it exists is because standard completion script is too slow - it might take seconds before Kubernetes cluster replies will all pod names. But `kubemrr` keeps the names locally, so the response comes back almost immediately.

Comment: To automatically load in future shells, you can do `echo "source <(kubectl completion zsh)" >> ~/.zshrc`

Comment: This is amazing. Spent 30 minutes trying to get bash completion working in Centos until I found this.

Comment: If you're running this on OSX and getting `command not found: compdef`, check this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477909/12737

Answer (score 18):

For `oh-my-zsh`, the easiest way to enable kubectl auto-completion is to add `kubectl` plugin in `~/.zshrc`:

```
# somewhere in your .zshrc
# kubectl: The kubectl completion script for Zsh can be generated with the command kubectl completion zsh. Sourcing the completion script in your shell enables kubectl autocompletion.
# kube-ps1: A script that lets you add the current Kubernetes context and namespace configured on kubectl to your Bash/Zsh prompt strings
plugins=(git kubectl Kube-ps1)
```

Comment: I had to add kube-ps1 to the list to get it to work `plugins=(git kubectl kube-ps1)` + another line `source <(kubectl completion zsh)`

Comment: I didn't need `kube-ps1`, but I did need `plugins=(git kubectl)` and `source <(kubectl completion zsh)`.

Answer (score 15):

I add this function to my $HOME/.zshrc.

It will lazy load complete function of `kubectl`

```sh
kubectl () {
    command kubectl $*
    if [[ -z $KUBECTL_COMPLETE ]]
    then
        source <(command kubectl completion zsh)
        KUBECTL_COMPLETE=1 
    fi
}
```

The oneline version:

```sh
(( ${+commands[kubectl]} )) && alias kubectl='test -z $C_KUBE && C_KUBE=1 && source <(command kubectl completion zsh); command kubectl'
```

Comment: `(( ${+commands[kubectl]} )) && alias kubectl='test -z $C_KUBE && C_KUBE=1 && source <(command kubectl completion zsh); command kubectl'`

Comment: can you please explain what does the command do which you left in the previous comment?

Comment: @MutantMahesh 1. if the executable binary file kubectl exist, make the alias; 2. check if the environment variable C_KUBE exist. if not exist, source completion script and set the environment variable; 3. let the aliased command 'kubectl' works like the real command 'kubectl'

Answer (score 7):

Try to add one line at the begining of you .zshrc file

```
autoload -U +X compinit && compinit
```

then add another line below

```
source <(kubectl completion zsh)
```

Comment: this is what helped me

Answer (score 6):

I want to suggest more clean setup, for all of you that are using `Oh My Zsh`.
The current accepted answer uses the command `kubectl completion zsh` and sources them to the environment.
Instead of doing that we would place them in the `plugins` folder, using the same command but modifying it to:

`kubectl completion zsh > ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/kubectl.plugin.zsh`

Now we have to define the plugins we want to load on ZSH start inside of our **~/.zshrc** config

```
...

plugins=(
  git
  ...
  kubectl
)

...
```

This solution has the benefit of keeping your config clean.
(Yes I know it is one line, but if you have to do this for 10 plugins it adds up! :) )